# Dont receive results other than those from first audio chunk

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I want some level of real-time speech to text conversion. I am using the web-sockets interface with `interim_results=true`. However, I am receiving results for the first audio chunk only. The second,third... audio chunks that I am sending are not getting transcribed. I do know that my receiver is not blocked since I do receive the inactivity message.

`json {"error": "Session timed out due to inactivity after 30 seconds."}`

Please let me know if I am missing something if I need to provide more contextual information.

Just for reference this is my init json.

```
{
 "action": "start",
 "content-type":"audio/wav",
 "interim_results": true,
 "continuous": true,
 "inactivity_timeout": 10
}
```

In the result that I get for the first audio chunk, the final json field is always received as `false`.

Also, I am using **golang** but that should not really matter.

EDIT:

Consider the following pseudo log

- localhost-server receives first 4 seconds of binary data `#lets say Binary 1`
- Binary 1 is sent to Watson
- {interim_result_1 for first chunk}
- {interim_result_2 for first chunk}
- localhost-server receives last 4 seconds of binary data `#lets say Binary 2`
- Binary 2 is sent to Watson
- Send {"action": "stop"} to Watson
- {interim_result_3 for first chunk}
- final result for the first chunk
- I am not receiving any transcription for the second chunk

[Link to code](http://gist.github.com/paritosh-gupta/7984bcfc0ec6871c3f83ee0541cd4bfd)

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Also, double-check the init json - this sounds like the expected behavior when `continuous` is omitted (or set to false)

Comment: I did double check my init json. I made a [gist] (https://gist.github.com/paritosh-gupta/7984bcfc0ec6871c3f83ee0541cd4bfd) for viewing code. Once it is working I will move my code into a public repository and put a link here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this question was to set the size header of the wav file to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the time-out message because the service waits for you to either send more audio or send a message signalling the end of an audio submission. Are you sending that message? It's very easy:

- By sending a JSON text message with the action key set to the value stop: `{"action": "stop"}`
- By sending an empty binary message

https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/websockets.shtml

Please let me know if this does not resolve your problem

Comment: The problem is not the time-out. The timeout is expected. Consider an audio file chunked into multiple parts. My problem is that I am unable to receive transcriptions for any but the first chunk of that audio file that I send to Watson. I am sending these chunks continuously without waiting for any result from Watson . I am keeping the size of each chunk under 4 MB and total size under 100MB. On completion I send the stop signal and wait till it time-outs for now.

Comment: Thanks for editing the original question and adding more information. It seems like your application's flow is correct. Can you please post an audio file for which you are seeing this behaviour? What happens if you feed that file through the Watson STT demo app? Do you see the same behaviour? (that demo page uses websockets as well, and produces interims). 

https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/

Comment: I am using the same audio file for testing as is being used for the bluemix demo. I found the file here. https://github.com/leonrch/SpeechToSpeech/blob/master/public/audio/Us_English_Broadband_Sample_1.wav. It works as expected. I am going to write quick code in python with the same workflow to see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but I've open-sourced a Go SDK for Watson services here:
https://github.com/liviosoares/go-watson-sdk

There is some documentation about speech-to-text binding here:
https://godoc.org/github.com/liviosoares/go-watson-sdk/watson/speech_to_text

There is also an example of streaming data to the API in the `_test.go` file:
https://github.com/liviosoares/go-watson-sdk/blob/master/watson/speech_to_text/speech_to_text_test.go

Perhaps this can help you.

Comment: I used the sdk but was still unable to resolve my issue. The code here is streaming the audio from file whereas I have chunks of audio. I get these chucks from a client on a websocket,I encode it to wav and then send them to watson. Any ideas?